# Adding colour variables to magento 2

Tags: magento2, less-css

I have just started to work with Magento 2 and I have the building blocks in place for my custom theme.

I'm only restyling the default luma theme and overriding the styling to fit in more with our business.

I am wondering how I can add more colors to **_colors.less**, Is it a simple case of adding more definitions to the file in the below location?

> lib\web\css\source\lib\variables

[image: Colours]

or do I override this somehow? I can't find much documentation on adding your own custom colors, just guides that use the default colours provided by Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom magento theme.

You have to override variable value in your custom theme **web\css\source_theme.less** file as below:

```
@color-white:#fff;
@button__color: red;
```

Comment: Can I just copy the _colors.less file into my own themes /lib/ folder and add colours to that?

Comment: @cz84 you can define your variable in above file and reuse it in your custom theme css. That is standard practice to override theme